# Tool for drawing UML state diagrams and generation of Table with transition description

Tags: uml, table

I am looking for a software to draw UML State diagrams and generate a table with a description of the transition between states. There are plenty of tools out there to generate UML state diagrams but I do not know of any that can generate a table description of the description of transitions and their actions. Normally this metadata can be inserted in various software when editing the properties of the transition. However, is there a tool that can also output a table description?

For example, take a look at this specification:

https://io-link.com/share/Downloads/Package-2020/IOL-Interface-Spec_10002_V113_Jun19.pdf

Page 87, Figure 48, and Table 50.

Is there a way to generate the state diagram and create a table with metadata about the transitions automatically?

Comment: Are you after a free solution or an enterprise one?

Comment: I'd rather look for a software that can turn such a table into a diagram. Seem to be the easier task. Usually any generated diagram is auto-layouted initially, and needs some tweaks to be more understandable and aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Either free or enterprise solution should be fine @kube

Comment: Generating the table is also a valid aproach. But I find it counterintuitive to build a transition table to generate a UML diagram, instead of drawing the diagram.